# Is the same way write this two type of struct?

Tags: c++, struct

In a test, I had to write some parameters in a struct car (some Features of a car). I wrote this code:

```
struct car
{
    string plate, template, brand;
    int    doors;
    float  engine_size;

    void ins()
    {
        cout << "Insert the template" << endl;
        cin >> template;
        cout << "Insert the engine size" << endl;
        cin >> engine_size;
        // it would continue but it is the same
    }
}
```

My prof told me that is wrong and he corrected it with this code:

```
struct car
{
    string plate, template, brand;
    int    doors;
    float  engine_size;

    void ins()
    {
        string t;
        int    e;
        cout << "Insert the template" << endl;
        cin >> t;
        t = template;
        cout << "Insert the engine size" << endl;
        cin >> e;
        e = engine_size
        // it would continue but it is the same
    }
}
```

Comment: If your prof missed the `template` issue, I wouldn't put much stock into what they say

Comment: Also there must be a `;` after the struct declarations.

Comment: Those assignments need to be the other way around.

Comment: What reason did the prof give for this "fix"?

Comment: @user463035818: looks like a professor, who maybe knows how to code in C and now teaches also C++.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Sorry about that. I removed the semicolons at the end of the class definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your prof has some weird misunderstanding of how `operator>>` works. Thats the only explanation I can come up with. However, I do not see any good reason for those "fixes". To the contrary, you do not need those additional variables and they just make the code more verbose for no gain. Note that even if you would need those additional variables, you should declare them only when needed not at the top of the function.

There are two real problems in your code: You miss a `;` after the class declaration and you cannot use `template` as a variable name.

Actually I think there must be some misunderstanding somewhere. Are you sure you understood the suggestions your prof made and you posted it here correctly? I suggest you to ask them again to explain why you should make those changes. Anyhow, if you teacher tells you "do it like that" without giving good reasons, then it is a terrible teacher. Dont follow rules you do not understand.

PS: last and least, I ignored the fact that you have the assignments the wrong way around. Your second snippet really could not be less correct...

Comment: Thank you, i wrote template because I’m Italian and I was searching for a meaning of a variable and I didn’t remember that template is a keyword. At the end I talked with the prof and he was agree with my code so I solved it